# What alternatives are there to truncating and inserting for refreshing a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Without using truncate and inserting the data in a table for refreshing purpose is any alternative solution there?

My table contain 2000 records; we will add some more records.

Comment: 10000 would be a big number in 20th century. Now it is a piece of cake. Use MERGE (or an alternative)

Comment: sorry we are having right now 2000 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2000 records is a **small** table, on any reasonable RDBMS and with virtually any reasonably modern hardware. Just `delete` the records you don't need or `update` the ones you do.